# Using jQuery to display text information about multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a self-contained sort of local web app using jQuery that
1) gets a list of image filenames from the user (assuming the images are all in the same folder as the .html file)
2) for each image, displays a thumbnail, the image file name, and the image's actual dimensions using image.naturalWidth and image.naturalHeight.

I managed to get it pretty much working the way I want - except that for each image displayed, the accompanying text info gets displayed after its respective the same number of times as the total number of images - i.e., the text is there once if there's a total of one images, twice if there's a total of 2 images, three times if there's 3 images, etc.

I think it has something to do with the use of $('img').each but I can't figure out how to structure it differently or even how to phrase a search for an answer.

I tried doing a JSfiddle but I can't get images to load from any remote servers for some reason. But that's fine for my purposes since I usually want to get a list of image dimensions locally.

The incremental number IDs for each image are sort of a vestigial part of an older version of this, but I'd like to keep it around in case I can think of another use for it - unless that's what's causing the problem.

Web boilerplate included just for context...

```
    <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    img {
        width: 250px;
    }

    .inner {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea textarea id="image_list" rows="10" cols="70" /></textarea>
    <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />
    <table>
        <div class="inner">
            <ul id='list'></ul>
        </div>
    </table>
    <script src="vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        /* increase ID by 1 for each iteration */
        var n = 0;

        function increment() {
            n++;
            return n;
        }
        /* add image thumbnail and dimensions on click */


        document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
            var arrayOfLines = $('#image_list').val().split('\n');
            $.each(arrayOfLines, function(index, item) {

                var text = arrayOfLines[n];
                increment();
                /* var text = arrayOfLines[].value; //.value gets input values */

                //Now construct a quick list element
                var li = '<li class="test" id="' + n + '">' + '<img src="' + text + '">' + '</li>';

                $('#list').append(li);

            });

            $('img').load(function() {
                $('img').each(function() {
                    var image = this;
                    var theWidth = image.naturalWidth;
                    var theHeight = image.naturalHeight;

                    $(this).parent().append(' - ' + $(this).attr("src") + ' - ' + theWidth + 'x' + theHeight + ' ');
                });
            });
        };


    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove the `$('img').each` completely as you are already in the `load` event which is fired for each image.

Comment: Brilliant! That did the trick. Thank you.